# Sending information between Android phone and PC

Tags: python, tcp

I want to send information from the accelerometer on my Android phone to my PC running python 3.3. I'm trying to use TCP sockets but I can't get my head around them in python.

I'm using RFO Basic on my phone if that's necessary but I know how to use TCP on that.

I just need to receive 3 numbers on my PC, how can I do this in python?

Comment: I've been reading though the docs and tutorials for the socket module.

Comment: tried http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/socketserver.html ?

Comment: @njzk2 It looks simpler. But I know nothing about TCP and I'm still a bit confused.

Comment: there is an example of simple connection handler. it should work pretty much out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with RFO Basic but here is what I recommend:

If RFO Basic supports HTTP requests, go with HTTP as you simplify the communication with a little bit of overhead.

If you have to use a TCP socket, take one of the example servers: http://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-tcpserver-example
If you take the StreamRequestHandler example, you can send new-line terminated data packets from the client which makes things quite easy.